# Error #1009 during flex alert or popup

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex-spark

I am getting error #1009 in my flex project whenever I alert or popup something -

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at mx.managers.marshalClasses::FocusManagerMarshalMixin/focusInHandler()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.managers::FocusManager/focusInHandler()
at flash.display::Stage/set focus()
at mx.core::UIComponent/setFocus()
at spark.components::RichEditableText/setFocus()
at spark.components.supportClasses::SkinnableTextBase/setFocus()
at Utils.LogUtils::Logger/ShowLogMessageWindow()[C:\Branch_Code\{XXXXXX - Hidden     Path- XXXXXXXX}\Utils\LogUtils\Logger.as:49]
at com.X.views::AppView/viewLogsButtonHandler()[C:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:996]
at com.x.views::AppView/__idViewLog_click()[C:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mxml:1433]
```

Comment: Without code cant say much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as with ant build script. It was working though flex builder but was failing in war generated through ant, I dump all config of flex builder and modified the ant script using all parameters used by config file and it starts working.